# Centered CSS menu with submenu

Tags: html, css, menu, center, submenu

I want to have a centered CSS menu with submenu. I could do a part of it (main menu) but I have problems on showing submenu. When I hover main menu items to show their submenu, problem starts ...

```css
* {
  font-family:arial;
}

#menu {
    height: 65px;
    background: #f3f3f3;
    text-align: center;
}

#menu ul {
    list-style: none;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
    top: 15px
}

#menu ul li {
    list-style: none;
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: 5px;
    margin-right: 5px;
    display: inline;
}

#menu ul li a {
    padding: 4px 10px 6px 10px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    display: inline-block;
    color: #666;
    transition: all 0.3s;
}

#menu ul li a:hover, #menu ul li a:focus, #menu ul li a.active  {
    background: #58c071;
    color: white;
}

.submenu {
  display:none;
  position:absolute;
  top: 5px;
  width: 200px;
  background:white;
}

#menu li:hover > ul {
  display: block
}
```

```html
<div id="menu" class="text-center">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Products</a>
      <ul class="submenu">
        <li><a href="">Product 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Product 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Product 3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/e8wyp6et/1/

Do you have any idea?

Comment: use `position:absolute;` for your sub menus. it is displayed block

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to have `position: relative;` on the submenu's closest parent and `left: 0`; on the `.submenu` selector :

In your question, it was added to the `#menu ul` which positioned the submenu relative to that.

```
#menu ul li  {
  position: relative;
}
```

and

```
.submenu {
  display:none;
  position:absolute;
  top: 5px;
  left: 0; /*this is needed to tell the submenu to align to the left of li*/
  width: 200px;
  background:white;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Kyle_/e8wyp6et/2/

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

`.submenu` get the css for your `ul` your target the `.submenu` by `#menu ul li > .submenu` and add `position:relative` to `li`

```css
* {
  font-family:arial;
}

#menu {   height: 65px;
  background: #f3f3f3;
  text-align: center;
}

#menu ul {
  list-style: none;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
  top: 15px
}

#menu ul li {
  list-style: none;
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: 5px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  display: inline;
  position: relative;
}

#menu ul li a {
  padding: 4px 10px 6px 10px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  display: inline-block;
  color: #666;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}

#menu ul li a:hover, #menu ul li a:focus, #menu ul li a.active  {
  background: #58c071;
  color: white;
}

#menu ul li > .submenu {
  display:none;
  position:absolute;
  top: 24px;
  width: 200px;
  background:white;
  left:0;
}

#menu li:hover > ul {
  display: block
}
```

```html
<div id="menu" class="text-center">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Products</a>
      <ul class="submenu">
        <li><a href="">Product 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Product 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Product 3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Give `position: relative` to `li` and not to `ul`

[Updated code](https://jsfiddle.net/e8wyp6et/3/)

Answer (score 0):

Your `submenu` properties are being overridden and the `display: inline` here is causing trouble.

Also your `ul li a` code is affecting the `li a` inside `submenu`

Try with the following code changes:

```css
* {
  font-family:arial;
}

#menu {
    height: 65px;
    background: #f3f3f3;
    text-align: center;
}

#menu ul {
    list-style: none;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
    top: 15px
}

#menu ul li {
    list-style: none;
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: 5px;
    margin-right: 5px;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
}

#menu ul li a {
    padding: 4px 30px 6px 30px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    display: inline-block;
    color: #666;
    transition: all 0.3s;
}

.submenu li a {
    padding: 10px 0 !important;
}

#menu ul li a:hover, #menu ul li a:focus, #menu ul li a.active  {
    background: #58c071;
    color: white;
}

.submenu {
  display:none;
    width: 120px;
    background: white;
}

#menu li:hover > ul {
  display: block
}
```

```html
<div id="menu" class="text-center">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Products</a>
      <ul class="submenu">
        <li><a href="">Product 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Product 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Product 3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```